# Can't upgrade vue cli due to repeating "Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-upgrade and try again."

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've tried to upgrade **vue cli,** and noticed that I need to install **@vue/cli-upgrade**.

```
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ sudo vue upgrade

  Command vue upgrade requires a global addon to be installed.
  Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-upgrade and try again.
```

So, I've installed **@vue/cli-upgrade** and try vue upgrade again, but the message is repeating.

```
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli-upgrade
+ @vue/cli-upgrade@3.12.1
updated 1 package in 7.273s
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ sudo vue upgrade

  Command vue upgrade requires a global addon to be installed.
  Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-upgrade and try again.
```

Also, the version of vue cli has still remained as 3.4.1

```
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ vue --version
3.4.1
```

How can I upgrade my vue-cli to 4? Thank you for your suggestion!

My environment is ubunto 14.04, and npm is version 6.13.7

```
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

````
ueda@klingsor:~/ml$ npm --version
6.13.7```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running:

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```